# Unable to connect to remote PC

Tags: windows-10, mac, remote-desktop

I am using my MacBook to connect to my PC. Both of these two computers are on the same network. My PC is connected to via Ethernet cable and my MacBook is connected to my wireless on the same network.I believe I have done all that was asked of me in order to establish the connection to my remote machine. However, I have been unsuccessful after weeks and weeks of trying and it is definitely getting on my nerves. I keep getting the same message, that says:

> Unable to connect to remote PC. Please Verify Remote is enabled, the remote PC is turned on and Available on the network, and then try again.

I have searched on this forum and went over every similar question with no success, my remote PC is on the same network and it powered ON. I have uninstalled and re-installed the RDC software the one by *Microsoft* on my Mac, even updated to the latest update today. What I am possibly doing wrong. My Ipad actually connects to my PC quite easily but my Mac can't. Can anyone please help me?

Comment: could you ping the PC ?

Comment: yes i ping the PC with it's works perfeclty but i still can't connect with my Mac

Comment: I would guess the the remote desktop service ( or remote assistance ) is enabled on the PC

Comment: The Remote assistance box is checked and on the Desktop "Allow remote connections to this computer is also checked" but I still can't connect

Comment: What about the windows firewall setting, anything in the event log regarding the connection, have you tried connecting to other services on the windows machine ( example : network share )

Comment: No I have not tried connecting to other services, how on the firewall setting the Remote Assistance and Remote desktop have been allowed to communicate trough firewall I guess that is why I can access the system when I use the Ipad.

Comment: Quick checks - On PC: Remote assistance 'on', Allow connections from any version, Advanced... 'allow control'. Then from Mac, RDC edit pane, PC Name 192.168.x.x[not the actual host name] User definitely an admin on the PC [not the Mac]. If that all checks out, also try the Beta RDC from https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/enterprisemobility/2016/03/30/remote-desktop-client-preview-for-mac-supports-multiple-monitors-and-more/

Comment: @Tetsujin I tried all suggestions and it didn't work but I tried the beta version on the link and it worked

Comment: interesting. I know the beta is considerably better than the release [I've been using it exclusively for over a year], but I wasn't sure of it's superior connection abilities. I'll attempt to generate an answer [which will mainly just be the same checklist, I guess ;)

Comment: Wonderful. Thank you very much. I took weeks on this problem

Answer (score 1):

From comments, only the recommendation of the current RDC beta seems to have done the trick, but I'll add the checklist anyway, for future Googlers.

This assumes that actual connectivity between the two has already been tested, by ping, arp etc.

Checks:-

You can access this by clicking Start & typing 'remote' & selecting 'allow remote access to your computer' [Slight cosmetic changes between Win 7 & 10 but similar]

Make sure Remote Assistance is enabled & that in Advanced that remote control is also checked.
For testing, set to Allow connections from any version of RDC. Once eliminated as a cause, switch back to Authenticated.

[image]

On the Mac, use the remote PC's IP address rather than host name, which eliminates any potential for the network's Master Browser not being up to speed on host names [decidedly more likely on a mixed-platform network, as Macs can often win the Master Browser election even if they were not supposed to]

Also, make sure the credentials used from the Mac are already authorised on the PC; an actual Admin account on the remote.

If all else fails, then try the new RDC beta [which has now been in beta for over a year & is superior to the current release in many aspects]

This MS Technet link always goes to the latest beta release, hosted on HockeyApp, & updates are semi-automatic after install.

https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/enterprisemobility/2016/03/30/remote-desktop-client-preview-for-mac-supports-multiple-monitors-and-more/